# Can dplyr summarise over several variables and list of tables

Tags: r, dplyr, lapply

I've been trying to use dplyr to summarise several tables over a list of tables that have the same structure:

```
LUZ_code  Type1  Type2 Type3 Type4 country
AT001L2  90142 752310 70700  7368      AT
AT002L2  82693 193892 30264   496      AT
AT003L2 119690 203394 28737   420      AT
AT004L2  42259  85892 14512   189      AT
AT005L2 113768  59841 15464   224      AT
AT006L1 126001 102170  9344   134      AT
```

I have applied several lapply in the script, so now I have the tables within a list called countries.

If I try to do it with a loop:

```
for (i in 1:length(countries)){
  years <- c("2010", "2030", "2030_ECL")
  db <- as.data.frame(countries[i])[,-1]
  db <- db %>%
    group_by(country) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(sum))
write.table(db, paste("country_conc",years[i], ".txt", sep = ""), 
          col.names = TRUE, row.names = FALSE, sep = "\t", quote = FALSE)
}
```

this seems to work without problems, but I was wondering if there is a way of doing with lapply. My attempt so far was:

```
summarise <- function (db){
 db <- (db)[,-1]
 db <- db %>%
   group_by(country) %>%
   summarise_each(funs(sum))
 return (db)
}
total <- lapply (concentration, summarise)`
```

i get this error message:

> Error in summarise(tbl, Type1 = sum(Type1), Type2 = sum(Type2), Type3 = sum(Type3),  : 
>     unused arguments (Type1 = sum(Type1), Type2 = sum(Type2), Type3 = sum(Type3), Type4 = sum(Type4))"

Thanks for any help,

Comment: What is `concentration` in the `lapply` call?

Comment: why dont you `bind_rows` the list of tables (while assigning an id) and then compute the summary?

Comment: You could use `summarise_at()` or `summarise_if()` to specify which column you want to summarise.

Answer (score 1):

I get it to work fine. I agree with @akrun, I don't know what `concentration` is. I think changing that to `countries` may fix your problem. Here is my working example.

```
c1 <- "LUZ_code  Type1  Type2 Type3 Type4 country
AT001L2  90142 752310 70700  7368      AT
AT002L2  82693 193892 30264   496      AT
AT003L2 119690 203394 28737   420      AT
AT004L2  42259  85892 14512   189      AT
AT005L2 113768  59841 15464   224      AT
AT006L1 126001 102170  9344   134      AT"

t1 <- read.table(text = c1, header = T)

t4 <- t3 <- t2 <- t1
t2$country <- "ZZ"
t3$country <- "YY"
t4$country <- "XX"

countries <- list(t1, t2, t3, t4)

mySummarise <- function (db){
 db <- (db)[,-1]
 db <- db %>%
   group_by(country) %>%
   summarise_each(funs(sum))
 return (data.frame(db))
}
total <- lapply (countries, mySummarise)
do.call(rbind.data.frame, total)
```

Comment: Defining your own `summarise` function while using dplyr might not be a good idea, as a side note

Comment: Sorry for being a bit messy, concentration is in fact countries. I also realized that the table does not reflect the whole picture: countries is variable (AT, BE, DK, etc up to 28 countries) and i want to summarize all the variables Type1... Type4 grouping by country, so in practice I should get a table with 28 rows and five columns, one for the country and one for each summarized type

Comment: Ok. I edited to take into account the comment by @docendodiscimus. I also edited so the function returns a data frame. So you now get a list with may data frames as the elements. Then you just have to convert that list to a data frame, or data table.